# What is the word for "inflation of in-game money as the player gets to higher levels of the game"?

Tags: word-request

What is the word that describes inflation of in-game money as the player gets to higher levels of the game?

I know this word exists because I seen it before as someone had told me, but now I can't find it any more.

The meaning of the word is that the higher the level of the player is, the more resources the player will make in-game.

This is bad because it will not make things fun for new players, and will cause hyperinflation of all resources. This usually happens in massive multiplayer online games.

Comment: Is this related to a specific game like poker?

Comment: Accretion: growth or increase by the gradual accumulation of additional layers or matter.

Comment: If a game is properly economically balanced, the last sentence in your paragraph shouldn't occur... for example, items that are designed for lower-level players should not be powerful enough to be wanted by higher-level payers, so they should stay cheap as the higher-level users sell them off in favor of better equipment.

Comment: @MamtaD, no, poker doesn't have this symptom since they're dependent on luck so the value of the money is based on your total money and bets on the table. | A game has this symptom for what I know is a [government simulation game](http://nationsgame.net/?refcode=897). The larger the nation is, the more farms it can build and the more money it can generate by selling food. Making big nations generating over 100k/day while small ones generating like 5k/day only.

Comment: @Catija, in this case, the game isn't economically balanced indeed.

Comment: Migrate to ELU?

Comment: This question might be better asked on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jasper, but that's for game development advice. I'm still here for English.

Comment: @XPMai -- Your question is written in perfect English.  The concept is an important one for game design.  Game Designers are far more likely to be able to answer your question than most native English speakers.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly (you seem to be specific about "money", but my terms are for more general ideas), so I'm gonna put a few keywords here: *fairness* is usually a design goal of games; to achieve this a game has to be *well-balanced*; when a resourceful player *dominates* a game, the game can be said that it's *imbalance*. Dominant players are also known as *overpowered* players. As [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Game_Balance#Implications_of_Imbalance) said, "Although the game may still be fair, it would become predictable and monotonous."

Comment: @DamkerngT., since you've the answer, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was an answer. (It has nothing about money.) Which term is the one you've heard (from that someone)? -- I can convert my comment to a supporting answer, if you'd like. ;-)

Comment: I forgot, but when I searched on Google with the term, the explanation was exact. Actually the right explanation is (just remembered): _The higher the level is, the faster growth it's._ There was an antonym for that, describing game with extremely slow growth.

Comment: @XPMai Just want to confirm my thought: I think the term you're looking for is *overpowered*, right?

Comment: @DamkerngT., it's closer now. I remembered the guy repeated the word *overpowered* few times, but that still isn't the word because *overpowered* is the meaning of the word.

Comment: I think the word is **lopsided**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like **devaluation**. I haven't heard it applied to resources in gaming, but it has the right meaning.

This [forum post](https://www.thebuddyforum.com/the-buddy-bots/legal/51095-academic-report-impact-bots-economics-gameplay-mmorpgs.html) mentions devaluation of goods, unfortunately the source on that page is missing.